# Dyanamically creating custom element's attributes null in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am creating a new custom element using `polymer-element` and using `attributes` to publish some attributes. Element is created like this

```
<polymer-element name = "my-element" attributes = "customId">

  <template>

    <div class = "content">
      Hello World
    </div>

    <style>
      .content {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function(){
        console.log("item id is : ", this.customId);
      }
    })
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Now when i am using this custom element in my html like

```
<my-element customId="foo"></my-element>
```

It works as expected and prints `item id is : foo` in console.
But when i create and add any custom element dynamically using javascript like

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  var myElement = document.createElement("my-element");

  myElement.setAttribute("customId", "bar");
  document.body.appendChild(myElement);

});
```

than the attribute `itemId` is `null` in ready function and it prints `item id is : null` in console, even when the html of custom element is created fine and manually getting property `itemid` in console gives correct `itemid`.
Whats going wrong here.
See the plnkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/9pbrgDF6lvWaT7auK74H?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
myElement.customId = "bar";
```

answer edited:

in your custom element you are looking for "customId" on ready and that attribute is not set yet. replace your ready function with a customIdChanged function and the code will work as expected.

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    customIdChanged: function(){
      console.log("item id is : ", this.customId);
    }
   })
</script>
```

Comment: I was already using this as a workaround, and was interested to know if it is a bug or expected behaviour. Anyway, accepting the answer as I think its a bug in polymer